# ejabberd add_rosteritem process_rosteritems

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am fairly new to ejabberd 16.06 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to use it with an external DB, Azure SQL server.

Almost everything works fine (except for a connection problem I talk about in another post).

What I am trying to understand better now, are the add_rosteritem and process_rosteritems commands.
I use add_rosteritem to add users to each others rosters, like so:

```
ejabberdctl add_rosteritem localuser localserver user server nick group subs
```

where subs is always "both". This command also create a record in the rostergroups table, as it seems I have to specify a group even tough I dont want to (I use a group called "all" for convenience) or the command does not work.

Point is, if I run `process_rosteritems list any any any any` all I get is `There are 0 roster items in total.`

Any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the command process_rosteritems works only with Mnesia. Ejabberd developers now mentioned this in the command description upon request.